# Localization Update in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization

I have a second .nib file that is a localized version of the main one in my Cocoa project.

I want to be able to perform some kind of 'update', as in, if I want to add new elements to the original, I want to be able to update it to the localized one. A solution can be deleting and re creating the localization, however the problem that I am facing is that if I have elements which I have changed from the second nib file (e.g. increase size of a label), this is then lost.

How can I do this 'update'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the free [Localization Suite](http://www.loc-suite.org/) for managing localizations of my app. It can synchronize changes in your main localization into the other localized NIBs/XIBs, without breaking layout/sizing adjustments you've made in the localized version. It handles the whole localization process pretty well. There are other tools and approaches to this problem, but this is the one I like.

For a completely different approach, see [Wil Shipley's blog post](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html) on the subject. The flaw in his approach is that it doesn't adjust sizing for localized versions. He addresses this by always making UI elements wide enough to fit the longest localization.

Comment: Those are some great approaches, I will investigate further, thanks!

Comment: Is there any official documentation for the Localization Suite?

Comment: The built in help seems to be broken in the latest release. That's probably worth reporting to the developer. However, as a slightly annoying workaround, you can open the help files directly by opening the path `/Applications/Localization\ Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Manager.help/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/pgs` (adjust if you didn't put the apps in /Applications of course).